# phantomjs command - permission denied

Tags: phantomjs

Running a VM with vagrant and virtual box but when I try to run phantomjs I get permission denied error.
Tried to chmod 777 the executable but the permissions are still -rw-rw-rw

I am running the command:
/usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/bin/phantomjs
I get
bash: /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied

Comment: PhantomJS is deprecated, better use nodejs and puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was the guest permissions for vagrant. Changed the permissions on the provision and now I can execute phantomjs.